# 401 Unauthorized returned on GET request (https) with correct credentials

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, ssl, httpwebrequest

I am trying to login to my web app using  HttpWebRequest but I keep getting the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Fiddler has the following output:

```
Result Protocol  Host           URL
200    HTTP      CONNECT        mysite.com:443
302    HTTPS     mysite.com     /auth
401    HTTP      mysite.com     /auth
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
// to ignore SSL certificate errors
public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
     return true;
}
```

---

```
try
{   
    // request
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://mysite.com/auth");
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Accept = "application/xml";

    // authentication
    string user = "user";
    string pwd = "secret";   
    string auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(user + ":" + pwd));
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

    // response.
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    // Display 
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

    // Cleanup 
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
}
catch (WebException webEx)
{
   Console.Write(webEx.ToString());
}
```

---

I am able to log in to the same site with no problem using ASIHTTPRequest in a Mac app like this:

```
NSURL *login_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.com/auth"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:login_url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setUsername:name];
[request setPassword:pwd];  
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/xml"]; 
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var uri = new Uri("https:/example.com/auth");
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Accept = "application/xml";

// authentication
var cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(uri, "Basic", new NetworkCredential("user", "secret"));
request.Credentials = cache;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

// response.
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Note the use of the `NetworkCredential` class instead of rolling your own authentication headers.

Comment: That's what I tried at first, and I still get 401. The only difference is that Fiddler says that there are no authorization headers present in the request.

Comment: Are you certain that the user name and password you are using are identical to the credentials you're using in the Mac app?

Comment: yes, i'm absolutely sure. is there another library like webrequest i can try?

Comment: You can use the HttpClient class from the REST Starter Kit, but I don't recommend it, as you'll just be making the situation more complicated. Better to stay with the relatively simple code you've got and get to the bottom of the problem. I've added a credential cache to force Basic authentication, but honestly this is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Turns out to be a server problem. I hadn't set it up to accept HTTPS connections for /auth.

Comment: If you want to use credentials of current user (assuming Ntlm): `cache.Add(uri, "Ntlm", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);`